# div's :nth-child(2) background-color is also changing body background-color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why is the `:nth-child(2)` changing the color of the `<body>` too?
When set to 1 or 3 this does not happen.

**The Code (http://codepen.io/kreitzo/pen/mPXzWv):**

```css
body {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This happens because `:nth-child(2)` looks to the second child of the first immediate parent, which is the `html` element... Therefore, `head` is the first child and `body` the second...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `body` tag is the second child of its parent (which is the root `html` tag). You can see this in the below screenshot. The first child of `html` tag is the `head` tag and the second child is the `body` tag.

[image]

The selector `:nth-child(2)` selects every element that is the second child of its own parent.

The `:nth-child(3)`, `nth-child(1)` selectors doesn't affect the background color of `body` because `body` is not the 3rd or 1st child of its parent.

If you want to select only the second child of a specific parent then you should mention the parent also as part of the selector (like the below):

- `body :nth-child(2)` - Selects all elements that are 2nd children of their respective parent at any level under `body`. So, this will not select the `body` tag.
- `body > :nth-child(2)` - Selects all elements that are 2nd children of their respective parent and the parent itself is a direct child of the `body` tag.

If you wish to select the second child only if it is of a certain type, then the element type should also be specified before the pseudo-class in the selector. For example, `div:nth-child(2)` will select only the `div` tags which are the second child of their respective parent.

Answer (score 1):

Because `body` is the second element of you html page

structure is like this

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

So your current css will catch all the second elements. Define css for elements of div like this

```
body {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do proper targetting of element like :

```css
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **div:nth-of-type(n)** instead of nth-child. This way you make sure only the *divs* are targeted.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have not specified nth-child for specific element but applied for any element selector. That's why the `:nth-child(2)` takes to the body element also as it is the second element from the root element `html`.

You may override the css rules for the body applied to `:nth-child(2)`:

```
/*just add :root  in your existing body to make it greater specificity*/
:root body{
  background-color: transparent;
}
:nth-child(2){
  background-color: green;/*this will not override to body bgcolor*/
}
```

But I would recommend you to use `:nth-child` for specific element which is better than the above way because in the above method `:root body` has greater specificity than previous and will make you some problem for simple element css rules overridings.

```
div:nth-child(2){
   background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your selectors `:nth-child(x)` could be read as `*:nth-child(x)` meaning every `x` child.

you can set it as `body :nth-child(x)` to limit it's scope to any direct `x` child of `body` 
or as `div:nth-child(x)` to limit it's scope to any div that is the `x` child of it's parent

```css
body {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```